# Polymorphic many-to-many relation, correct definition and how to retrieve related models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, polymorphic-associations

I'm trying to build a small database to handle responsibilities.

Different users can be responsible for different things ("managables")

- projects
- functions
- packages
- documents

A user can be responsible for n managables, and a managable can have n responsibles.

I have the following models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :responsibilities
end

class Responsibility < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :managable, :polymorphic => true
belongs_to :user
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :responsibles, :as => :managable, :class_name => 'Responsibility' , :source_type => "Project"
end
```

I just generated the models using `rails g scaffold User` and added the relations afterwards, in the model.rb files.

I expected to be able to use something like:

```
u = User.new
p = Project.new
r = Responsibility.new

r.user = u
r.managable = p
```

and retrieve the responsible for each manageable with something like `p.responsibles` which gets me a

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `responsibles' for #<Responsibility:0x532f1a0>
```

It also looks to me as if the `managable_type` column does not get filled. It's always 0.

What am I missing?

Comment: You want `p.managable`

Comment: have you saved r after setting the managable & user associations?

Comment: Can you show when/how you exactly get the `NoMethodError` during your call to `p.responsibles`?

Comment: The error shows when writing p.responsibles in the IRB - and yes, p, u and r were saved.